# variable as argument in pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I have written a program for creating number of threads. The number can be passed as a command line argument or default value is 5. The problem I am facing is printing the thread number passed as an argument to pthread writer function.

Below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *writerThread(void *args)
{
  int id = *((int *)args);
  printf("In thread %d\n", id);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numThreads;
  if(argc != 2)
    numThreads = 5;
  else
    numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

  pthread_t *tId = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads);

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
  {
    pthread_create(&tId[i], NULL , writerThread, &i);
  }

  // wait for threads
  for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    pthread_join(tId[i], NULL);

  if(tId)
    free(tId);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In thread 2
In thread 0
In thread 3
In thread 2
In thread 0
```

Why 0 and 2 are coming two times ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must make sure each thread gets its own separate variable because there's no guarantee the that data pointed at will be the same as you intended by the time the thread gets to run. So, you need an array of thread numbers, and pass a different entry to each (`int thr_num[numThreads];  … { thr_num[i] = i; pthread_create(…, &thr_num[i]); }`. And, unless you think the number of threads will be very high, I'd use a VLA, or even a fixed size array, of the `pthread_t` structures — similar to the `thr_num` array suggested before. Or create an array of a structure with a `pthread_t` and an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the threads

```
pthread_create(&tId[i], NULL , writerThread, &i);
```

`i` continues its life... thus when you print `*(int*)args` in the thread. you get the current value of`i` that keeps being used and changed in the *main* function.

You might want to allocate an array of integers that contain the thread id and store the id during the thread creation

```
int tids[numThreads];
for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
   tids[i] = i;
   pthread_create(&tId[i], NULL , writerThread, &tids[i]);
}
```

This way, each thread has an argument that points to its own personal data (in that case, an integer).

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Ring Ø's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746967/841108), in your particular case of passing a small integral number to your thread routine, you could cast to an `intptr_t` type that argument, and code:

```
void *writerThread(void *args) {
  int id = (int)((intptr_t)arg);
  printf("In thread %d\n", id);
}
```

then

```
for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
   pthread_create(&tId[i], NULL , writerThread, (void*)((intptr_t)i));
}
```

this is possible since `pthread_create` just passes an *uninterpreted* [pointer] word, which could actually be a cast from `intptr_t`, which is guaranteed to have the same size than pointers.

So you don't always need the last argument to `pthread_create` to be a *valid* (dereferencable) pointer.

BTW, on my Linux/Debian/x86-64 system, pointers (e.g. `void*`) and `intptr_t` have (like `long`) 8 bytes, but `int` is 4 bytes.

In the usual case, the last argument to `pthread_create` is often (as a rule of thumb) a unique pointer to some [heap allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) `malloc`-ed zone (and you should later `free` it appropriately, usually after the corresponding `pthread_join`).

Notice that your code should test against failure of `malloc` and should have:

```
 pthread_t *tId = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads);
 if (tId == NULL) { perror("malloc tId"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

since in the unlikely case that `malloc` failed your code exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the first argument to `pthread_create` should be a valid address of some `pthread_t`.

Comment: As if this wasn't answered enough times already!

Comment: Several of the answers you flagged as duplicate don't mention the `intptr_t` cast trick (which is specific to the case of passing an integral number to the thread routine). So I don't think my answer deserves your downvote.